# What data type should I use in cv::Mat.at<data_type> when using CV_8SC3, CV_16FC3, CV_16FC1?

Tags: c++, opencv

When looing through the image and to index the `(i, j)` , `OpenCV` provides the method `at` in `cv::Mat`. In  order to get the correct value of that pixel we need to specify data type carefully ,or we might get some unexpected value.

For example, if you use `CV_16SC3` to create cv::Mat like below :

```
cv::Mat img(h, w, CV_16SC3, cv::Scalar(-32, -64, -64));
```

When indexing the value you should use `cv::Vec3s` like :

```
img.at<cv::Vec3s>(i, j)[c]
```

If you use soem other type like `img.at<cv::Vec3f>` you would get some wrong value.

Now we know the importance of filling right data type, the table below is all I know what data type to put in to get correct value .

```
    CV_8UC3  -> cv::Vec3b   CV_8UC1  -> uchar 
    CV_8SC3                 CV_8SC1  -> char
    CV_16UC3 -> cv::Vec3w   CV_16UC1 -> ushort
    CV_16SC3 -> cv::Vec3s   CV_16SC1 -> short  
    CV_32SC3 -> cv::Vec3i   CV_32SC3 -> int

    CV_64FC3 -> cv::Vec3d   CV_64FC1 -> double
    CV_32FC3 -> cv::Vec3f   CV_32FC1 -> float
    CV_16FC3 ->             CV_16FC1 ->
```

I would like to know for `CV_8SC3, CV_16FC3, CV_16FC1`, what data type should I write in order to get the correct value ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: `CV_16FC1` should be 16 bit float, which is not standardized, but maybe you have in your environment a `half` type or a `float16_t` type? Another way is to read the values by a type of same size and reinterpret the memory from the received data. For example I've once written an 2x 16 bit float embedded in a 32 bit float on cuda, when cuda didnt have half precision floats yet.

Comment: once you have a 16 bit float type you can write your own struct with 3x16 bit, like struct `Vec3f_16{half1;half2;half3;};` and override the `[ ]` operator if you like to. Same for `CV_8SC3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own specialization on your demand. `cv::Vecxx` are just a bunch of shorter [aliases](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga595458e63aa1443ddd5c51fa71d70e2a) for for the most popular specializations of Vec<T,n>

So:

- for `CV_8SC3`, you might use `cv::Vec<char, 3>`,
- for `CV_16FC3`, you might use `cv::Vec<cv::float16_t, 3>`.
- for `CV_16FC1`, you might use `cv::Vec<cv::float16_t, 1>`.

Besides, if you just want to iterate through a `cv::Mat`, there are actually many ways to do so, for example, the `at` method have this overloaded [version](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a305829ed5c0ecfef7b44db18953048e8):

```cpp
template<typename _Tp >
const _Tp& cv::Mat::at (int i0, int i1, int i2) const
```

And i hope this official document will help you more:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html